# Android Urban Airship Push :UAirship.takeOff() cannot be resolved in Activity

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I put this code in onCreate method in class which extends Application and it worked perfectly .But in class extends Activity  shows error :

```
UAirship.takeOff(this, new UAirship.OnReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) {

            // Enable user notifications
            airship.getPushManager().setUserNotificationsEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

In the class which extends Activity it shows cannnot resolve the takeoff method .
What is the concept behind it

Answer (score 0):

You should only call takeOff once, preferably in the main application or using autopilot. Its most likely not resolving because you are missing an import statement. At the top of your file make sure you have `import com.urbanairship.UAirship;`

Comment: yes i import it . its only resolved in the class which extends Application .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UAirship.takeOff(this.getApplication(), new UAirship.OnReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) {

        // Enable user notifications
        airship.getPushManager().setUserNotificationsEnabled(true);
    }
});
```